# How to import DDMathParser in iOS 8 project?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6.3.1

I am totally new to swift and developing my first application for iOS. I need to use DDMathParser with it. I followed guide at their site but i am getting errors at import statement

1. Expected identifier in import declaration
2. Expected expression

Import statement syntax:

#import "DDMathParser.h"

I followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975796/adding-a-simple-library-to-an-xcode-4-project) guide.

Comment: That's how you import an Objective-C class.

Comment: Did you put the import statement into the bridging header file? (Hopefully not into a Swift file :)

Comment: Did you try everything from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift ?

Comment: i used [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975796/adding-a-simple-library-to-an-xcode-4-project) as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Bridging header files solved my problem. Thanks