# Git: How to handle git libraries in project

Tags: git, github

I've a Xcode project which itself has Git Source Control. In a *Libraries* folder I've cloned eight other Git project from [GitHub](https://github.com/). They are located inside my own Git repository and I've added all these libraries to my git in a commit.

Instead of having the code of all these git libraries in my repository, is there a way to let git download their code from their repo when I make a clone of my repo? Or is it normal to include other git repos inside a project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140985/setup-a-git-external-for-remote-repo

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure do the following:

1. Remove the 3rd-party-folder which you might have added already
2. Open your Terminal and execute the following commands

   ```
   cd /path/to/your/main/repo
   git submodule add git@github.com:someuser/somerepo.git somerepo
   git commit -m "Added submodules"
   ```
3. Now instead of copying those files you'll have a reference to the other repository in your project:

**Edit:**

Now if you want to update the submodule to a more recent commit you can do the following:

```
cd somerepo
git pull # You can also checkout a branch / tag etc.
cd ..
git add somerepo
git commit -m "Telling the main repo to update the reference to the referenced repo"
```

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't I use this instead `git submodule add https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView.git Libraries/AQGridView` instead of `git@github.com:...`?

Comment: How can I update these submodules? Are they pulled automatically when I pull my repo or do I have to go inside their folder and make a `git pull`?

Comment: @DennisMadsen Yes you can do a git pull which does pull any changes in `somerepo` however, you have to tell your main repository to update the reference too. See my updated post. BTW: I find submodules quite handy since you don't have to duplicate code from repositories, that are already accessible for you via git.

Comment: @DennisMadsen: You can use any repository path that Git will accept; SSH, HTTP(S), Local path, etc.

Comment: For anyone who's interested. The screenshot were done with [Git Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/), which I can recommend using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [git submodule](http://help.github.com/submodules/) and clone repositories [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796927/1003780)