# How to update github libraries consumed in project

Tags: android, github

I am using an open source library project from GitHub in my Android Application. I've modified that library to work with my specific needs. Now that library has been updated with more cool features.

If I want to use the updated library, I've to download it and again I've to put my older modifications manually. Instead of that is there any process, so that I can use latest libraries from GitHub still with my modifications.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so there is a way for Git same as using library from Maven repository.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897019/git-how-to-handle-git-libraries-in-project
This questions has the answer

Answer (score 2):

You want to [fork that repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) on Github, add your changes onto that, then [merge the upstream changes](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches) once they come out. You could even add your fork of this library as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) in your main project.

Hope that helps. Good luck!