# Is it possible to create or access libraries globally with cmake?

Tags: cmake

My project is located in this filepath:

```
C:\Users\zaina\OneDrive\foo_directory\bar_projectname
```

The libraries and git repositories, which I want to use globally, are located in this file path:

```
C:\dev\github\foobar
```

For example [This repository is about controlling Tello drone with c++ language, and I cloned this](https://github.com/LucaRitz/tello.git)

I used Cmake GUI to configure the build and Visual Studio to build the libraries, but I simply can't include it in my project by invoking:

```
#include <tello/tello.hpp>
```

So there must be something that might help.

[I tried git submodules and it worked fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897019/git-how-to-handle-git-libraries-in-project), but it only works for a single project and not globally.

So I was wondering that is there a possibility to set a cloned repository as a global library or create one. If it is, then how?

I tried this as my CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(foo)

# Setup testing
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

enable_testing()
  
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE ${tello_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

target_link_libraries(tello_test PRIVATE tello)
```

But that did not work, because my program can't find the tello header files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have done it. But I don't want to use submodules every time for each project. I want to do it as a global library

Comment: If you want to build the lib as part of your project, consider [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#examples).

Comment: ok thanks. But i had trouble running tello drone library in cmake. it says tello.dll is not found.