# vagrant include plugin source in my project

Tags: vagrant

I would like to minimize the setup for users of my vagrant project.

I already think that installing Virtualbox and Vagrant are too steps too many for users of my project.  See [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2703) for more info on that.

Because my project depends on a few plugins, rather than require the user to use `vagrant plugin install ...`, I would like to automate installation of the plugins.

**Question 1:** Is it an ok practise to include the plugin source in my project tree, and include the plugin using `Vagrant.require_plugin "plugin-dir/plugin-name"`?

**Question 2:** Will this approach work?

The plugins I depend on are available on github so I can add them as git submodules as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140985/how-to-set-up-a-git-project-to-use-an-external-repo-submodule)

---

**Edit**

The approach above did NOT work for the [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin

Comment: Similar question in the Vagrant ML: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/szfadztOWIw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar need and the method I went with was to add the following at the top of my `Vagrantfile`:

```
unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-omnibus") || ARGV[0] == 'plugin'
  origargs = ARGV.join(" ");
  puts "Plugins not found"
  exec "vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus;vagrant #{origargs}"
end
```

It doesn't really answer your questions I guess but it works for me, I found that I also needed to add `sudo` in front of the `vagrant plugin` command for my ubuntu setup, but as you don't state what OS you are running that might not be relevant.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question, but I was looking for something that would support cross platform hosts.