# git push realm.framework makes git stuck when writing objects

Tags: git, realm

I've been trying to push changes where I've added realm.framework (static framework) to my xcode project, but each time it gets stuck when pushing to git.

I've identified that its realm.framework that itself is getting stuck; no other file or attempt to push to git gets stuck when writing objects.

```
Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 73.81 MiB | 4.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

I've tried the post buffer

`$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

How can I push realm.framework to my git project without it getting stuck?

Many thanks

Edit

I've found out that its specifically the

`Realm` file, which 227.3MB in size.

I've tried to use SSH and HTTPS, both with the postbuffer.

Sadly, they are both stuck.

I guess the only solution I have right now is to gitignore the file and put in an NSAssert to inform the user to manually install/add Realm.framework

Thanks

Comment: Don't add frameworks and libraries directly to your project. Use cocoapods or git submodules.

Comment: I can't use the cocoapods because Realm doesn't work with the latest cocoapods project `N.B.: The CocoaPods 1.0.0 Release Candidate versions are not supported at this time. Please use the latest stable version.` and I have to add it manually

Comment: Won't a git submodule not have the same issue; trying to push a 227mb file upstream?

Comment: Perhaps this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140985/how-to-set-up-a-git-project-to-use-an-external-repo-submodule

Comment: Okay I will review this. Thanks

Comment: @cardigan: You can try the latest CocoaPods beta with the latest version of Realm. These contain a fix for this issue.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted the answer given by @jurgemaister