# Setting up a Submodule with the files in PWD?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a submodule to an existing project. I followed the instructions at [How to set up a git project to use an external repo submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2140985/608639), but the directory structure is wrong. I am aiming for a "it just works" so users are not hassled.

The initial clone and submodule process:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
cd cryptopp
git submodule add https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools.git
git submodule update --remote
```

The submodule only has one file at the moment, and its a `README.md`:

```
$ find . -name README.md
./cryptopp-autotools/README.md
```

What I need to accomplish is, add the submodule's files to `PWD` and not the subdirectory `cryptopp-autotools`.

How do I setup the submodule such that the submodule's files are in `PWD` and not subdirectories?

---

The [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) man page seems to indicate we can specify a `<path>`, but here's the result of trying to do so:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
cd cryptopp
git submodule add https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools.git $PWD
git submodule update --remote

'/home/jwalton/cryptopp' already exists in the index
```

Comment: A submodule always exists in a directory separate from the parent project (because a submodule is a git repository).  You can't merge two separate repositories into the same work tree.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. It sounds like submodules are the wrong tool for the job. What should we do to merge the files from two different locations into a single project? Branches are not an option because they pollute the log files. We stopped using branches and switched to unique repos.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use `git` as a software distribution mechanism (" I am aiming for a "it just works" so users are not hassled."). That's not really what it was built for. If you really need to work with separate repositories, I would learn to love either `git submodule` or `git subtree` and re-arrange things so that your project works with the directory structure implied by either of these solutions.