# Add single solution with multiple projects to Github via Visual Studio

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 is it possible to take a solution with multiple projects and upload it into a single Github repo without having to move one of the project's directory?

Is there a dependency setting somewhere in my "startup" project that will include my other project (.dll) and push all of it to a repo?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need a git submodules. Refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140985/how-to-set-up-a-git-project-to-use-an-external-repo-submodule) and perhaps this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAWeHOm2d8E).